# "Inject" predexed libraries into project before building

Tags: android, android-build

I'm maintaining a framework that lets users write own android applications that are then compiled on a web server. Each user has his own project structure created upon opening the page. Every project created this way uses some custom libraries.

Building for the first time would be significantly faster if I could place an already dexed version of these libraries into the project. Is there any way how I could predex them, so they are recognized when copied into other projects?

Comment: Hi Panmari, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same problem :)